# Mandarin vs. Cantonese: 令 vs 讓 for making something happen

Tags: grammar, mandarin, cantonese

In Cantonese, it's common to hear someone say 令 when referring to making something happen.

Example: 妳咁做令我開心 (You make me happy when you do this.)

Some friends claimed Mandarin doesn't use 令 this way and uses 讓 instead， making the equivalent sentence 妳這樣做讓我開心。

However, Pleco lists 令人難忘 as "creating an unforgettable impression." This suggests 令 can be used like this in Mandarin.

1) Is the use of 令 different in Canto vs Mandarin? Is 妳這樣做令我開心 not proper Mandarin grammar?

2) If there is a difference, when do you use 令 and when do you use 讓?

Comment: it's also correct to say: 妳這樣做令我開心 in mandarin. its pretty much the same as 让 in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For the meaning of 'to make/ to cause',  the usage of 令 in colloquial Cantonese  cover the usage of 令(force/make), 使(cause/make) and 讓(allow/make) in Mandarin

Example:

令人唔開心 (Cantonese) = 令人不高興/ 使人不高興/ 讓人不高興 (Mandarin)

*The difference between 令 使 and 讓 is in 'degree of emphasis'; colloquial Cantonese typically use final particles for emphasis*

> In literal Cantonese (SWC- Standard written Chinese) It is the same as Mandarin

Example:

令人不高興/ 使人不高興/ 讓人不高興 (Mandarin) = 令人不高興/ 使人不高興/ 讓人不高興 (SWC)

> Cantonese do not use 讓 (make/ cause) colloquially at all. However, there's a word we use in colloquial Cantonese for 'make/ cause'  that is not used by Mandarin. This word is '等', but it has to be used with a 'cause'

Example:

"(等)佢熟透" = "(wait) for it to be cooked completely"

"加猛火(等)佢快啲熟透" = "use high heat (to make) it cooked completely faster"

In Mandarin, it would be "加猛火(讓)它快點熟透"

*One more note: Cantonese do use the compound words 使到 and 令到 colloquially. The same as Mandarin*

Answer (score 1):

1) Is the use of 令 different in Canto vs Mandarin?

> Firstly the word 令 has multiple meanings.  I believe the usage are same for Canto vs Mandarin as long as you're referring to the same meaning of the word.

Is 妳這樣做令我開心 not proper Mandarin grammar?

> Instead of improper grammar, it's more of unpopular usage, like usually 讓 is used.

2) If there is a difference, when do you use 令 and when do you use 讓?

> For Canto it's pretty much the same,  讓 is usually used for formal written (novel / books) while 令 for oral / casual writing.  Again it does not apply to 令's other meanings.

Worth to mention that for idiom, the words are not interchangeable.